# Azure AD, to get access to Azure SQL

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, blazor-server-side

I have made a Blazor app, that authenticate users in my AzureAD, that works out of the box and are very smooth. Users are from different customers and are in a ADgroups for every customer, but use the same APP, and have roles from the App-setting in AzureAD.

Problem:
The customers have their own SQL with data and users must only see data from their own Azure-SQL, so I have a long list of SQL databases, one for each customer. When I validate a user, I can only get the AD-group-GUID from tokens, so how do I differentiate the SQL databases, for every customer?

My solution so far is to have a manually updated table with the customerID and AzureAD group GUID and use this to allow access to the users, to their data, but this seems to be a workaround.

Can some of you think of a better solution to this problem, where users must only access one of N* databases, allowed from a AzureAD group?

Comment: Is that these databases are in the same tenant and sql server?

Comment: The AD is in one tennant and SQL databases are hosted in another tennant.

Comment: Is that you use Azure ad auth to access azure sql?

Comment: No, there is a system-user in every database. That is why I have a missing link between AAD and SQL.

Comment: According to my understanding, your web app is projected by azure ad but you use sql auth to access Azure SQL. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Regarding the issue, I think you use the app role AD auth,. you can define app role for every azure sql database. Then assign app role for the user. Aftering doing that, when the user do AD auth, we can get app role form the user id token and use the role to know which database the user can connect. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451347/how-to-use-azure-ad-for-authentication-for-multiple-instances-of-same-applicatio/59497926#59497926